# RTF - New page without extra line an the top of the page

Tags: c#, rtf, page-break, paragraphs

What is the code for delimiting pages in RTF?

I am using:

```
\page\par
```

It works but this code puts a break-line at the top of each new page. So all my pages except first page start with a break line. How can I erase this break-line?

The '`\par`' is representing a paragraph and as I see like in HTML this parahraph is delimited by the rest of the content through spaces.

Answer (score 5):

In RTF, `\par` represents a paragraph **break**. `\page` alone will suffice to create a page break without a blank line after it.

Comment: What software are you using to view the RTF document? It could be a bug with that...
There are a couple of other ways to set a page break in RTF. `\pagebb` will create a page break before the next paragraph. `{\sect}\sbkpage` will create a new page and a new "section", which, depending on your document, might have unintended consequences...

Comment: that's really helpful, you solved me a big problem! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

I'm using Word 2016 to view the RTF, and `\page` alone simply does not generate a page break.  But `\page\par` does.  I don't know why.  It has been driving me crazy for a few hours.

I finally found a hack:  set the font size to zero on the extraneous `\par`, then set it back when you are done.

So if you are working with font size 10, the code will be `\page\fs0\par\fs20`.  Remember that the `fs` size is double the font size.

I totally hate this.  But it is the only thing I've found that actually works.  If anyone finds something better, please post it.